# How to remove a previously drawn ControlP5 dropdown list in Processing

Tags: java, processing, control-p5

I've written a sketch in Processing that creates 3 nodes on which a user can click to display a dropdown list. Is there a way to make the dropdown list disappear on, say, an outside mouseclick or a release of the mouse button? I figured I could just call the background in the Draw section and it would overwrite the lists, but that appears not to be the case because they're not actually parts of the drawing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always good to look at the documentation (included with the library).

From the [ConrolP5 developer's site](http://www.sojamo.de/libraries/controlP5/#features)

> Show, hide, load, save Controllers that have been added to your sketch
>   can be arranged in tabs and groups to keep your controller sets
>   organized. All controllers are drawn on top of a processing sketch by
>   default. Several key combinations allow you to show and hide the user
>   interface, and to saved and loaded ControlP5 properties,
>   ControlP5properties → example. The position of a controller can be
>   adjusted during runtime by moving a controller while the ALT-key is
>   pressed.

`Class DropdownList`inherits from `Class ControllerGroup` which has a method: **hide**

```
 hide

public java.lang.Object hide()

    Specified by:
        hide in interface ControllerInterface
```

So to accomplish what you want, you need to track the mouseClick and then target the specific item you want to hide.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I'm a beginner, and it never even occurred to me to go sifting through the documentation (which now, of course, seems obvious to me). Thanks again!